# SVG Icon Animation not working on ArcGIS JavaScript

Tags: symbology, svg, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, animation

I am working on Angular 11 project having ArcGIS JavaScript version 4.17.
When placing points on map using `GraphicsLayer` am using custom SVG Icons, the ones with animation are not showing perfectly on the map. they are showed as a static picture, even though they are showed perfectly animated on the Developer tools-> source portal.

Note that I had tried `SimpleMarkerSymbol.path` and `PictureMarkerSymbol.url` but the same problem exists.

Code:

```
symbol = {
      type: 'picture-marker',
      url:`./assets/icons/svg/abnormal.svg`,
      width: '45px',
      height: '45px'
    };
const pointGraphic = new Graphic({
      geometry: point,
      symbol: symbol 
    });
     this.graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);
```

Answer (score 0):

Animated SVG images are not currently supported in ArcGIS API for JavaScript 4.17. At the 4.18 release in a few days, the documentation will be updated to clarify this.